# I have a css form and cannot center it

Tags: css, forms, width, fixed

I have a website I am working and the form isn't sitting in the right place it keeps shifting and moving I spoke to tech support they gave me some code it worked for a bit now it's off again can someone please help.

This was the code:

```
button.et_bloom_submit_subscription {
float: right;
position: fixed;
top: 7px;
right: 310px;
}

.et_bloom .et_bloom_form_content .et_bloom_popup_input {
width: 25%;
}
button.et_bloom_submit_subscription {
width: 21% !important;
}
.et_bloom .et_bloom_inline_form {
left padding: 60px;
}
.et_bloom .et_bloom_inline_form {
margin: 0;
}
.et_bloom .et_bloom_header_outer {
display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1100px) { 
.page-id-453 .et_bloom_form_content {
width: 100% !important; 
margin: 0 auto !important;
}
.page-id-453 .et_bloom_form_content .et_bloom_popup_input {
width: 25% !important;
margin-right:2%;

}
.page-id-453 .et_bloom_form_container button {
width: 45% !important;
padding:13px;
top:auto !important;
left: auto !important;
margin: auto !important;
float: right !important;
}
}
```

And this is the website www.askleewellard.com (form is right below the graphic).

Comment: Please post your HTML or prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: As in the entire css or you mean the HTML of the site (cuz I am using wordpress).